# Listener declared in a Kotlin Object class

Tags: android, kotlin, architecture

I have an `object` class in Kotlin which is a manager - let's call it `KManager` - that manager is inside an independent module (*moduleA*). There is another module (*moduleB*) where I'm using `KManager`.

**Rule:** *moduleB* knows about *moduleA*, but *moduleA* shouldn't know anything about *moduleB*.

I created like a bridge (interface) to communicate *moduleA* with *moduleB*, because of there is some shared logic that needs to run in both sides. The interface is declared in the `KManager` as:

```
//moduleA
object KManager {

    var bridgeShared: BridgeShared? = null
    ....
}
```

Interface:

```
interface BridgeShared {
    fun foo()
}
```

Now, I have a class in the *moduleB* where implements `BridgeShared`. When the app starts I'm initializing `bridgeShared` like this:

```
//moduleB
class BridgeSharedImpl : BridgeShared {

        KManager.bridgeShared = this
        ....
}
```

I'm getting `KManager.bridgeShared` in the *moduleB* and executing the interface's functions in another classes, something like:

```
KManager.bridgeShared.foo()
```

The question here is, is it harmful to have a listener declared inside an `object` Kotlin class and grab it whenever I need it?

**NOTE:** No real names used here, just to describe the scenario.

**UPDATE:**

Extra Steps:

*moduleA* receives like an external event, it is processed and then the result is received by the "Observer" who subscribed to the `BridgeShared` listener, that "Observer" is the *moduleB* but *moduleA* doesn't care about it (the rule).

**moduleB**

```
class BridgeSharedImpl : BridgeShared {

   KManager.bridgeShared = this

   override fun eventProcessed() {
      //stuff
   }

   override fun fetchData() {
     //stuff
   }

   fun callAnotherFunction1() {
     KManager.anotherFunction1()
   }
}
```

**moduleA**

```
interface BridgeShared {
    fun eventProcessed()
    fun fetchedData()
}

object KManager {

    var bridgeShared: BridgeShared? = null

    fun anotherFunction1() {
      //not-related to BridgeShared, called from outside
    }

    fun anotherFunction2() {
      //not-related to BridgeShared, called from outside
    }
}

class EventProcessor {

  fun eventReceived() {
    //stuff
    KManager.bridgeShared?.eventProcessed()
  }  

}

class DataFetcher {

  fun dataReceived() {
    //stuff
    KManager.bridgeShared?.fetchedData()
  }  

}
```

On the other hand, I'm taking advantage of `KManager.bridgeShared` in the *moduleB* to call the same functions inside the same *moduleB* because I don't have access to the instance of `BridgeSharedImpl`everywhere, just where it was instantiated.

Now, the *moduleB* uses the `KManager` singleton to execute other functions not related to the BridgeShared.

Comment: It is OOD question and it will, no doubt, spawn a lot of controversial answers. Here is a dangerous line between objective and subjective...
Also, details are too opaque to offer a single win-win solution.



Surely, this architecutre looks dreadfully. I mean, singleton mutable object to serve as a mediator? Haven't you consider insantiating an object that knows how to perform business process and relies on abstractions to delegate or ask for some functionality, whereas concrete implementors of these interfaces will be located in `moduleB`?

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin yeah .. I don't feel good with this. is the object that you propose like BridgeSharedImpl, what kind of details can I give you to clarify the implementation?

Comment: If you could provide some abstract steps (fake, of course) that are being performed in both sides (`...because of there is some shared logic that needs to run in both sides`), it would be cool. What I see now is that `moduleA` uses a singleton object so obtain an object that should be used to execute a part of the buisness-logic flow. Then why the singleton is needed? If I understood correctly, then specific implementations of `BridgeShared` could just be passed as a constructor parameter to an object in `moduleA` instead of contacting between modules via the singleton.

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin just added an update. (... then specific implementations of BridgeShared could just be passed as a constructor parameter to an object in moduleA... )  .. got it, but I need the `BridgeShared` in another places in the same `moduleA`

Comment: It's extremely complicated architecture...
First thing I would recommend is to eliminate "singleton access". The most lightweight thing that can be done is, sure, passing `Listener` to a constructor of `EventProcessor` and `DataFetcher` classes. If you need a one instance, you can just create an `Abstract Factory` that will take singleton instance and will pass it to the constructors of mentioned classes. Thus, unwanted coupling and dependency will be removed from these classes.

Comment: Sure, this advice is bounded with existing solution: I ain't offer to change something globally. I want to make changes cheap.
Honestly, I think that singleton abstract factory is preferable over singleton business logic object. Personally I don't like singletons in any representation, and by some people it is considered as antipattern, but Erich Gamma in his Design Patterns book recommends to use singleton with abstract factories if a single configuration is needed for the factory.

Comment: So, if single factory will be configured with `Listener` instance and will provide instances of `DataFetcher` and `EventProcessor`, then the only place of coupling will be in this factory instead of **all the objects that need to notify about some event**.
But if you want something more clean, I would recommend to analyze some DI solutions that exist for the platform/language you are working with.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @AndreyIlyunin. I wanted to use a DI framework, but, for internal desitions, it is not possible. I was thinking about the solution about the Abstract Factory, that sounds good, but, if the Abstract Factory class is initialized with the `Listener` it should be `static` to be able to send it in the new instances of the classes `DataFetcher` and `EventProcessor` which are inside a static function, isn't it?

Comment: I think that the less evil is to have singleton abstract factory (I mean, your **class** will have, for example, one static field, which is `INSTANCE`, and two static methods: `getInstance()` which will return the factorie's singleton instance, and `initialize(Listener listener)`, that will create an object for static `INSTANCE` reference with a constructor that recevies a `Listener` object. Than, **instance methods** (non-static) would be something like `DataFetcher createDataFetcher() {  return new DataFetcher(this.listener);  }`, whereas `this.listener` is a instance field of the factory.

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin just follow your recommendations, I will post the solution.

Comment: Sure :)
But beware about thread visibility issues here, if you use parallel environment. Proper synchronization should be used to guarantee that all threads won't see stale reference value.
Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the recommendations, I applied the Factory solution to avoid saving the `BridgeShared` inside a Singleton.

**moduleA**

```
class BridgeFactory(private val bridgeShared: BridgeShared) {

    companion object {

        lateinit var bridgeFactory: BridgeFactory

        fun initialize(bridgeShared: BridgeShared) {
            bridgeFactory = BridgeFactory(emmaShared)
        }
    }

    fun eventProcessor(): EventProcessor {
        return EventProcessor(bridgeShared)
    }

    fun dataFetcher(): DataFetcher {
        return DataFetcher(bridgeShared)
    }

}

class EventProcessor(private val bridgeShared: BridgeShared) {

  fun eventReceived() {
    //stuff
    bridgeShared.eventProcessed()
  }  

}

class DataFetcher(private val bridgeShared: BridgeShared) {

  fun dataReceived() {
    //stuff
    bridgeShared.fetchedData()
  }  

}
```

**moduleB**

```
class BridgeSharedImpl : BridgeShared {

    init {
        BridgeFactory.initialize(this)
    }

   override fun eventProcessed() {
      //stuff
   }

   override fun fetchData() {
     //stuff
   }

}
```